# Generating crystal report in VS2010

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting an error while generating crystal report in vs2010. Error 
 The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll

Answer (score 1):

Open web.config and the static page of your aspx document. Both of them are containing different versions of assemblies. From web.config copy '13.0.2000.0' (version of assembly) and paste it in your aspx document's static page. The error has been removed.